# Getting A Thread Variable Runtime Value?

Tags: multithreading, tcp, c++-cli, networkstream, binaryformatter

I have trying to do the following and having problems. This is within a C++/CLI form using Visual Studio 2015. I am using TCP to communicate between a server and client, and trying to use BinaryFormatter as the method of communication.

```
private: System::Void ServerForm1_MouseMove(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
       //some code that does stuff
       bf->Serialize(socketStream, myobj);
```

BinaryFormatter is declared in the private: section of the overall main form. 
socketStream is declared at the same location, but is not assigned a value until the RunServer method

```
void RunServer() {
        TcpListener ^listener = gcnew TcpListener(IPAddress::Any, 12345);
        listener->Start();
        connection = listener->AcceptSocket();
        socketStream = gcnew NetworkStream(connection);
```

which is called when the form is constructed

```
ServerForm1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        readThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &ServerForm1::RunServer));
        readThread->Start();
    }
```

The error is happening whenever I try to do the first code sample with bf->Seralize. The value of socketStream in that function is showing as null. I've also tried declaring a binarywriter inside of RunServer() and then using the BaseStream property of binarywriter. BinaryWriter also is being displayed as null outside of RunServer().

How can I access an instanced version of socketStream or BinaryWriter outside of RunServer() so my BinaryFormatter has the proper stream to serialize to?

Comment: It is a simple bug in your code, you are not making sure that the socket is connected before you call Serialize().  Just add if (socketStream != nullptr), valid because the .NET memory model promises that reference variable updates are atomic.

Comment: Where should I add this? whenever I do bf->Serialize?